# MySQL how to generate Summary for current day

Tags: mysql

i am quite new in programming i have to create my task summary for current day.
i have 3 table one for `countries` one for `task` and one for `customers`

**here is the table defination**

```
CREATE TABLE `countries` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `code` varchar(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `customer` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `country` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `country` (`country`)
);

CREATE TABLE `task` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `design_type` enum('Digitize','Vector','Quote') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Digitize',
  `order_type` enum('New','Edit','Revision') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'New',
  `customer_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `priority` enum('High','Medium','Low') NOT NULL Default 'High',
  `remarks` text NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `customer_id` (`customer_id`)
);
```

now i have to create summary like that.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
|  Country Name  |  New  | Revision  |  Edit  |  Total Order  |
+----------------+-------+-----------+--------+---------------+
|  Australia     |  2    |    1      |  0     |    3          |
|  Pakistan      |  4    |    0      |  2     |    6          |
|  United State  |  3    |    1      |  1     |    5          |
|  United Kd     |  2    |    2      |  0     |    4          |
+----------------+-------+-----------+--------+---------------+
```

i have build some dummy data is [**sqlfiddle.com**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/55569)

any suggestion will be appreciated.
**Big Thanks**

Comment: Now you have the data in sqlfiddle - what you need to do is make an attempt to solve the problem yourself. Break the problem down into parts - query the tasks table to get todays tasks, then build up the query to join the other tables & select the required columns. If you run into problems add your query to sqlfiddle & ask a specific question.

Comment: i am really confuse to solve this query i really don't have any idea to make this type of query. can please make this query

Comment: As I said - break the problem down into smaller pieces. Joining the tables & selecting all results is a very basic SQL query & you should be able to find out how to do that in basic SQL tutorials - have you managed to do that yet? Grouping & adding columns that require a conditional sum are a bit more advanced - but I suggest that you google how to do those. You shouldn't be trying to use StackOverflow as a code writing service - you need to show you have made attempts yourself & ask specific questions to why it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: NOTE -  If you are going to show the query that you have done so far - then add it as an edit to the original question rather than as a comment - then it can be better formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After sometime finding and searching on internet i really didn't get any idea related this post. but by putting more effort i guess it could be solve by aggregate functions and finally i get desire result. here is my final query..

```
SELECT c.name, c.code,
SUM(IF(t.order_type = 'New',1,0)) new,
SUM(IF(t.order_type = 'Revision',1,0)) revision,
SUM(IF(t.order_type = 'Edit',1,0)) edit
FROM task AS t
JOIN customer AS cus ON cus.id = t.customer_id
JOIN countries AS c ON c.id = cus.country
WHERE t.date = CURRENT_DATE AND t.status != 'Completed'
GROUP BY c.id
```